# What's a good way to monitor the number of files/folders in a directory in a reactive context?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do within a shiny app:

```
## run a script that creates subdirectories
system('Rscript /path/to/dir/dir_generating_script.R')
## observe path and count new directories created
observe({
  d_count <- list.dirs("/path/to/dir") %>% length()
  showNotification(paste0(
    "Current dir count: ", d_count
  ))
})
```

The problem I'm having here is that the notification message is not updating as d_count is changing while the script is running in the background. The message only updates when the script has finished running, but I'd like to see the count increment while it's running. Is there a better way to monitor a directory reactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactivePoll()` to create a reactive file count that is checked regularly (here 1 second):

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("result"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  file_count <- function() {
    list.dirs(".", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE) %>% 
      length()
    }
  current_file_count <- reactivePoll(1000, session, file_count, file_count)
  output$result <- renderText(current_file_count())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```